# Saving logged in user's foreign key as a foreign key

Tags: cakephp, save, foreign-keys, cakephp-3.0

So I have 3 tables: Users, Customers and Bookings.

The relationship and foreign keys between each:

Users hasOne Customers. Customers belongsTo Users. 
Users.id = Customers.user_id

Customers hasMany Bookings. Bookings belongsTo Customers.
Customers.id = Bookings.customer_id

In an add form, when making a booking, I want to save the logged in user's customer id as the booking's customer_id.

Fields:

In Users table:

> -id
>   -username
>   -password
>   -role_id (connected to roles table)
>   -created
>   -modified

In Customers table:

> -id
>   -user_id (the foreign key connected to Users table)
>   -name
>   -created
>   -modified

In Bookings table:

> -id
>   -customer_id (the foreign key connected to Customers table)
>   -payment_id (connected to payments table)
>   -created
>   -modified

Comment: isnt user == customer? What have you tried? Did you follow conventions?

Comment: User and customer are separated for security purposes - User has username and password, Customer has name & phone number. I've tried: $customer = $booking->Customers->findByuser_id('Auth.User')->first();

Comment: what is secure about it?

Comment: Sorry, jumped to conclusions. But in my database, my user table is connected to another table, i.e. all Customers are Users, but not all Users are Customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try below code**

```
$booking = $this->Booking->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $data = $this->request->data; #Store post data to a variable
    $customer_id = #Find and assign customer ID to a variable
    $data['customer_id'] = $customer_id; #Assign customer ID to saving data
    $booking = $this->Bookings->patchEntity($booking, $data);
    if ($this->Bookings->save($booking)) {
        #SAVING SUCCESS
    } else {
        #ERROR SAVING
    }
}
```

**Finding Customer ID (Loading Model)**

```
$this->loadModel('Customers');
$logged_in_user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$customer = $this->Customers->find('all')->where(['user_id'=>$logged_in_user_id])->first();
$customer_id = $customer->id; #Or $customer['id'];
```

**Finding Customer ID (Without Loading Model)**

```
$logged_in_user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$customer = $this->Bookings->Customers->find('all')->where(['user_id'=>$logged_in_user_id])->first();
$customer_id = $customer->id; #Or $customer['id'];
```

Comment: So with this line: $customer_id =, where do I go about finding the customer ID? For example, in debug mode, clicking on Session and then Auth shows the currently logged in user details, but not the Customer's details.

Comment: Give me your customers table `fields` name @W.Lau

Comment: Still getting a database error. Anyway, I'll update my OP with the fields.

Comment: What kinds of error? Can you give me screenshot link? @W.Lau

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`team17_system_build_update`.`bookings`, CONSTRAINT `bookings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`))

Comment: Check and confirm `Users` , `Customers` is exists and meet the foreign key constraint. @W.Lau

Comment: I prefer, At first execute your Booking query manually from `phpmyadmin` and If there is no error, then try to adjust it to `CakePHP` @W.Lau

Comment: Managed to get it working, using your code modified a bit: $this->loadModel('Customers');
        $customer = $this->Customers->findByUser_id($this->Auth->user('id'))->first();
        $booking->customer_id = $customer->id;

Comment: Actually i didn't run the code. I just wrote it for you! Thank you @W.Lau

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Footprint plugin](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint), which handles exactly this problem pretty transparently.